# Object mapping for [] tried to parse field [] as object, but found a concrete value

Tags: python, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm working on a project where a Lambda function processes change stream events from an SQS queue and transforms them into a specific format before uploading them to Elasticsearch. The Lambda function extracts event details, transforms dates to a specific format, and then updates the Elasticsearch index.

However, I'm encountering an error related to the Elasticsearch mapping when processing date fields like `lastPutDate`. The error is as follows:

```
[ERROR] RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'object mapping for [lastPutDate] tried to parse field [lastPutDate] as object, but found a concrete value')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/main.py", line 146, in lambda_handler
    record_change_stream_event(change_stream_event)
  File "/var/task/main.py", line 127, in record_change_stream_event
    es_client.index(index=es_index, id=doc_id, body=doc_body)
...
```

This is a snippet of my Lambda function code:

```py
def record_change_stream_event(change_stream_event):
    ...
    # Process and convert dates
    convert_nested_dates(doc_body, 'lastPatchDate')
    convert_nested_dates(doc_body, 'lastPutDate')
    ...
    # Attempt to update Elasticsearch mapping
    new_index_mapping = read_new_index_mapping() // This will read the index mapping from a local file.

    try:
        es_client.indices.put_mapping(body=new_index_mapping, index=es_index)
        logger.debug('Updated mapping for index {}'.format(es_index))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Error updating mapping for index {}: {}'.format(es_index, e))
    doc_body.update({'operation': op_type, 'timestamp': str(change_stream_event['clusterTime']), 'timestampReadable': str(readable)})
    es_client.index(index=es_index, id=doc_id, body=doc_body)
```

The Elasticsearch mapping is about 1800 lines long, and I have nearly 18 date fields like `lastPatchDate`. The date values are formatted as `"datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time).isoformat() + 'Z'"`.

**My question is**: How can I change the Elasticsearch mapping to correctly interpret these date fields as concrete values rather than objects?

I have tried using `es_client.indices.put_mapping` to update the mapping where i will get the mapping manually update the mappings to a concrete value. but that approach is hardcoded way of doing things and that too resulting in some issue.

Any insights or suggestions on how to modify the mapping for these date fields in a proper way would be greatly appreciated.